# solve the path to css in jsp

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, spring-mvc

I'm using Spring MVC 3.0 to construct a rest-style url.
Here is part of my code:

```
@RequestMapping(value = {"/", "/posts"}, method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String getNewestPosts(Model model, HttpServletRequest request)
        throws DataAccessException {
    return getPostsByPage(1, model, request);
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/posts/page/{page}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String getPostsByPage(@PathVariable long page, Model model,
        HttpServletRequest request) throws DataAccessException {
    // ... get the posts by page number
}
```

I wrote two methods. One handles the request from url "/posts" which means retrieving the first page of the posts , and the other one handles the request from url "/posts/page/{page}" which means retrieving the posts according to the path variable {page}.
And the problem is that all the two methods above point to the same view which is a jsp file, but they're in different paths("/posts, "/posts/page/xxx"). The css path (../style.css) can not adapt both of them.
I try to solve it by using absolute css path(/style.css), which means the web application works only if the application is deployed on a root path("/").
I would appreciate it if you could help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `<c:url>` tag, which prepends the context path to an absolute URL.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<c:url value="/style.css" />" />
```

or

```
<c:url var="cssUrl" value="/style.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="${cssUrl}" />
```